# assign variable by bash script during variable declaration time

Tags: bash, variables, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

For my **azure-pipeline.yml** file, I would like to assign variable by bash script to get the name after the slash from the repoName as my imageName

```
variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-18.04'
  repoName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
  imageName: ${repoName##*/}
```

The **repoName** is `top/cci` I expected the print out result for **imageName** is `cci`. But the result is ${top/cci##*/}

How can I use the bash script to get the strings after the slash during the variable assignment?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Can you tell what value you want to have in `imageName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this format:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-18.04'
  repoName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
  imageName: $(basename $(repoName))

steps:

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo ImageName = $(imageName)

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo ImageName = $(imageName)
```

The `imageName: $(basename $(repoName))` seems to work well on my side.

```
variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-18.04'
  repoName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
  imageName: $(basename $(repoName))
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

If this is not what you're looking for, maybe you're looking for [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)...